# browser application in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, iframe

I created a program in Apache cordova. My program is just an iframe for opening a web site.
but I have problem in android versions before 5 with scrolling my page. My problem is in the picture:

[image]

As can be seen, the text isn't being placed correctly.

My code is this

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">        
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" id="theParent" style="height:100%; padding:0px; overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;">
        <!--<button id="myBtn" onclick="gourl();"> go to url </button>-->
        <iframe style="width:100%; border:0px; height:100%;" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src="http://shahreman.biz" id="urlshow">
        </iframe>

        <script>
            //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", gourl());
            //var physicalScreenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
            var physicalScreenHeight = window.innerHeight;
            //physicalScreenHeight=(physicalScreenHeight/100)*97;
            var heightiframe=physicalScreenHeight+"px"
            //alert(heightiframe);
            document.getElementById('urlshow').style.height=heightiframe;
            function gourl()
            {
                document.getElementById('urlshow').src = 'http://shahreman.biz';
            }
        </script>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Along with an image please clearly describe your problem and ask a relevant question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

That's simply because you're not suppose to build an app in Cordova using iframes. You can use PhoneGap and put your html and everything inside a new project, and run it with PhoneGap Desktop emulator or using CLI, to see how it works in mobile device. from the capture it seems you have padding of divs issues. good luck